# how to create click event to display set interval time

Tags: javascript, alert, setinterval, mouseclick-event

I have a Javascript setInterval function set up to display like a timer. I'd like to display the time that is on the timer when a "next" button is clicked so the user can see how long they've spent on a certain page. I'm unsure how to connect the setInterval with a click event. This is what I have, but it's not working.

```
let timerId = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(++sec % 60);
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10));
    }, 1000);
    function myFunction() {
  alert document.getElementById("timerId").innerHTML = "Time passed: " + timerId);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show the timer running while the user is on the page or do you just want to show the final time when user actually clicks the button?

Comment: If you only want to show how many time a user spent on a page only when he click on some button, you only need to get the time difference between the time when he arrived and the time when he click. Store a new Date() in a var at arrival and calculate the difference with the Date he clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```js
var initialTime = new Date().getTime();
var timeSpent='0:00';
var timeElement = document.getElementById("time");

timeElement.innerHTML = timeSpent;

let timerId = setInterval(function () {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        timeSpent = millisToMinutesAndSeconds(currentTime - initialTime)
        timeElement.innerHTML = timeSpent;
    }, 1000);
    
function millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
  var minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000);
  var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
  return minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
}

  function alertFn(){alert(timeSpent)}
 document.getElementById("rightButton").addEventListener('click',alertFn);

 document.getElementById("wrongButton").addEventListener('click',alertFn);
```

```html
<h1 id="time"></h1>
<button id="rightButton">Right</button>
<button id="wrongButton">Wrong</button>
```

Comment: I want the time running while the user is on the page & the time that is on the timer displayed in an alert once the button is clicked. It's actually a "right" button and "wrong" button the user can click. Can I add the alert to both buttons?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be better if you put setInterval method inside the function. After that you could give your function to an event listener as an argument.

Your code should look something like this

```
let timerId;
function displayTime() {
    timerId = setInterval(() => {
        // your code

    }, 1000);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', displayTime)
```